# How can I troubleshoot Python "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>"

Tags: python, path, importerror

I'm trying to use Fontcustom to create an icon font using svg files and fontforge. I'm on OSX.7. However, whenever I run the program I get the error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

What do `<prefix>` and `<exec_prefix>` mean here? How can I fix the problem?

On my system, `python --version` reports `Python 2.7.1`. I checked the corresponding library directory `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`, and it includes `site.py`. Why isn't that module found?

Comment: Were you using virtualenv?

Comment: I'm getting a similar error in macOS x after updating it to Catalina. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'"

Comment: I got a similar error but that was because I had not set Python Path correctly. Setting that removed the error

Answer (score 83):

If you made a virtual env, then deleted that python installation, you'll get the same error. Just `rm -r` your venv folder, then recreate it with a valid python location and do `pip install -r requirements.txt` and you'll be all set (assuming you got your requirements.txt right).

Comment: This worked for me when I upgraded my server from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I also had to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954983/installing-scrapy-on-mac-pyasn1-distribution-not-found

Comment: `cd <virtual-env-dir>` then `pipenv shell` then `pipenv --venv`

Comment: 1. I'm getting the above but have no idea where <virtual-env-dir> is?
and 2. `pipenv` gives me: `zsh: command not found: pipenv`

Comment: This was the issue that caused the same error message for me, but the fix that worked was `pipenv --rm`

Comment: this was helpful for me: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RebuildingVirtualenvs/

Answer (score 66):

Try `export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local`.  Python should be installed in `/usr/local` on OS X.

This answer has received a little more attention than I anticipated, I'll add a little bit more context.

Normally, Python looks for its libraries in the paths `prefix/lib` and `exec_prefix/lib`, where `prefix` and `exec_prefix` are configuration options.  If the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable is set, then the value of `prefix` and `exec_prefix` are inherited from it. If the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable is not set, then `prefix` and `exec_prefix` default to `/usr/local` (and I believe there are other ways to set `prefix`/`exec_prefix` as well, but I'm not totally familiar with them).

Normally, when you receive the error message `Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>`, the string `<prefix>` would be replaced with the actual value of `prefix`.  However, if `prefix` has an empty value, then you get the rather cryptic messages posted in the question. One way to get an empty `prefix` would be to set `PYTHONHOME` to an empty string.  More info about `PYTHONHOME`, `prefix`, and `exec_prefix` is available in [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables).

Comment: What should I do if I am using two different virtualenvs: One for Python 2.7 and one for Python 3.6?

Comment: Had this issue when compiled C code that calls Python function using Cython as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589868/call-python-code-from-c-via-cython/58847011#58847011 . The executable complained about the missing libraries and modules. Defining both PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue while using Python installed with `sudo make altinstall` on Opensuse linux. It seems that the compiled libraries are installed in `/usr/local/lib64` but Python is looking for them in `/usr/local/lib`.

I solved it by creating a dynamic link to the relevant directory in `/usr/local/lib`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload/ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
```

---

I suspect the better thing to do would be to specify `libdir` as an argument to `configure` (at the start of the build process) but I haven't tested it that way.

*Edit:* Can confirm that `./configure --libdir=/usr/local/lib` works, and is probably better than creating links.

Comment: Indeed that solved my problem. I also moved the file libpython3.8.a and pkgconfig folder as described here https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/7cmawa/installing_latest_python/

Answer (score 9):

change PYTHONHOME to the parent folder of the bin file of python, like /usr，which is the parent folder of /usr/bin.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and spent a few hours trying to fix it. I fixed the prefix error by changing the path but I still had an encoding import error. This was fixed by restarting my computer.

Answer (score 1):

My pycharm ce had the same error, was easy to fix it, if someone has that error, just uninstall and delete the folder, use `ctrl+h` if you can't find the folder in your documents, install the software again and should work again.

Remember to save the scratches folder before erasing the pycharm folder.