# Call python code from c via cython

Tags: python, c, cython

So I'd like to call some python code from c via cython. I've managed to call cython code from c. And I can also call python code from cython. But when I add it all together, some things are missing.

Here is my python code (`quacker.pyx`):

```
def quack():
    print "Quack!"
```

Here is my cython "bridge" (`caller.pyx`):

```
from quacker import quack

cdef public void call_quack():
    quack()
```

And here is the c code (`main.c`):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "caller.h"

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  initcaller();
  call_quack();
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get this exception:

`Exception NameError: "name 'quack' is not defined" in 'caller.call_quack' ignored`

The missing pieces I'm suspecting:

- I haven't called `initquacker()`
- I haven't included `quacker.h`
- Cython didn't produce any `quacker.h` - `only quacker.c`
- `caller.c` doesn't import `quacker.h` or call `initquacker()`

I'm not really sure that it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do, but it seems to me that it ought to be. I'd love to hear any input you might have.

Edit:

This is how I cythonize / compile / link / run:

```
$ cython *.pyx
$ cc -c *.c -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
$ cc -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -ldl *.o -o main
$ ./main
```

Comment: Can the quacker file just be a python .py file, or does it have to be a .pyx one?

Comment: Can you post the way you compiled all of those ?

Comment: @brm Yes, in fact I would prefer that, since all the python code I want to access is already in .py files.

Comment: @hivert I've added my homemade build script in an edit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you rename the `quacker.pyx` to `quacker.py`, everything is actually correct. The only problem is that your program won't search for python modules in the current directory, resulting in the output:

```
Exception NameError: "name 'quack' is not defined" in 'caller.call_quack' ignored
```

If you add the current directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable however, the output becomes the one you'd expect:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=".:$PYTHONPATH" ./main 
Quack!
```

When running the python shell, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) the current directory (or the directory containing the script) is added to the `sys.path` variable automatically, but when creating a simple program using `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize` this does not seem to happen. Since the PYTHONPATH variable is also used to populate the `sys.path` python variable, the workaround above produces the correct result.

Alternatively, below the `Py_Intialize` line, you could add an empty string to `sys.path` as follows by just executing some python code, specified as a string:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nsys.path.insert(0,'')");
```

After recompiling, just running `./main` should then work.

#### Edit

It's actually interesting to see what's going on if you run the code as specified in the question, so without renaming the `quacker.pyx` file. In that case, the `initcaller()` function tries to import the `quacker` module, but since no `quacker.py` or `quacker.pyc` exists, the module cannot be found, and the `initcaller()` function produces an error.

Now, this error is reported the python way, by raising an exception. But the code in the `main.c` file doesn't check for this. I'm no expert in this, but in my tests adding the following code below `initcaller()` seemed to work:

```
if (PyErr_Occurred())
{
    PyErr_Print();
    return -1;
}
```

The output of the program then becomes the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "caller.pyx", line 1, in init caller (caller.c:836)
    from quacker import quack
ImportError: No module named quacker
```

By calling the `initquacker()` function *before* `initcaller()`, the module name `quacker` already gets registered so the import call that's done inside `initcaller()` will detect that it's already loaded and the call will succeed.

Comment: Alternatively you can set the `PYTHONPATH` with `PySys_SetPath("...");` where ... is what you want.

Comment: @hivert Just doing that would set sys.path to only '.', so I'm guessing that would make it difficult to find other standard modules

Comment: Great answer :-). I think I prefer to put the `sys.path.insert` call at the top of `caller.pyx`. And that `PyErr_Occurred` trick works great.

Answer (score 9):

In case there's anyone wondering how would it work in Python 3, here's my solution after struggling a bit as a Cython newbie.

**main.c**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "caller.h"

int
main() 
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("caller", PyInit_caller);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("caller");
    call_quack();
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**caller.pyx**

```
# cython: language_level=3
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '')

from quacker import quack

cdef public void call_quack():
    quack()
```

**quacker.py**

```
def quack():
    print("Quack!")
```

Finally, here's the **Makefile** that compiles everything:

```
target=main
cybridge=caller

CC=gcc
CFLAGS= `python3-config --cflags`
LDFLAGS=`python3-config --ldflags`

all:
        cython $(cybridge).pyx
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c *.c
        $(CC) *.o -o $(target) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f $(cybridge).{c,h,o} $(target).o $(target)
        rm -rf __pycache__
```

Comment: On Windows with MSYS2, PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH had to be set to run the executable without errors or warnings. In my setup it is set to c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is not what you want but I got it working by the following changes:

in quacker.pyx I added

```
cdef public int i
```

To force Cython to generate the `.h` file.

An then in the main:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "caller.h"
#include "quacker.h"

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  initquacker();
  initcaller();
  call_quack();
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that works :-). It is a bit hacky though. To use this method I have to put bogus attributes in all my python files. It also means that my c code has to know about all my python modules. I'd prefer that the c code only knows about the bridge (caller.pyx).

Comment: You actually don't need that header file. In C functions can be declared implicitly, so the code also works without the header file, just calling initquacker()

Comment: That's right! I actually just gave up after the compiler gave me this warning: `main.c:7:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'initquacker' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this using CMake and ended up recreating this sample. You can find the repository with complete working example [here](https://github.com/aniongithub/native-python-caller).

You can build and run the example using either Docker on the CLI or a Visual Studio [devcontainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers).