# C++ header file with Cython

Tags: python, c++, header-files, cython

I am new to cython. I have this small cython code example:

hello_cython.pyx

```
cdef class Employee:
   'Common base class for all employees'
   cdef public int empCount

   def __init__(self, name, double salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      Employee.empCount += 1

   def displayCount(self):
     print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

   def displayEmployee(self):
      print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary\
```

I compile this cython code with setup using
setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("hello_cython.pyx")
)
```

Now goal is to be able to use class Employee from both other python scripts and C++ programs. So I thought of producing a header file (.h) when I do setup.py it creates a .h file and a .so file that can be used from another python script and .h(corresponding .cpp file generated) file so that it can be included in another C++ program where I can instantiate class Employee and use its member functions. As mentioned in this thread 
([Call python code from c via cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589868/call-python-code-from-c-via-cython)) I added

```
cdef public int i;
```

before the class definition and when I do setup.py it creates the header file. But the problem is, when I include it in another C++ program the class Employee is not available. Am I missing something in setup file or in .pyx file .. ? Or am I doing something which is not possible in this approach.

I am using python 3.2 to run the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. You want

```
cdef public class Employee:
    ...
```

as the `public` keyword determines, what will be visible to C/C++ using the generated header file.

Using just `cdef public int i;`, you make only the variable `i` public.

See also: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html