# Run python in C++

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have an application written in C++ and a testing system (also in C++). Testing system is pretty complicated and hard to change (I want to make only small changes). My class looks like this:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void somefunc(const AnotherClass& file) {
}
};
```

There are several functions inside. My testing system creates Derived class instance and then uses it's methods to do some stuff.

Now I want to be able to write a solution in Python. I need a two-way integration. My idea is to write Python function, which will be executed every time when `somefunc` is called. And I don't want to lose variables' values in Python from one launch of function to another. And I also want to be able to use methods which are defined in the Base class instance from python. How can I achieve these things?

I chose Boost.Python for these purposes. For now, I understand, how to use c++ function, or even simple class in Python after some work. But I don't understand how to launch Python function from c++.

The second question - is Boost.Python a good choice? I need something very fast and, at the same time, easy to use.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I never tried boost-python, but as far as I can remember you could use `#include <python.h>` to embed python in C/C++. From there it's pretty easy. [here's link](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).
Although I would re-think the whole approach if I were you. Because it sounds like you're trying to do something needlessly complicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using Cython for this sort of thing. Adapted examples from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589868/call-python-code-from-c-via-cython). (*Edit*: Upon request, I added an extended example that wraps a C++ class, see further below.)

---

***Edit:*** Simple example, one way (C++ -> Python).

quacker.py:

```
def quack():
    print("Quack!")
```

cquacker.pyx:

```
from quacker import quack

cdef public void cquack():
    quack()
```

main.cpp:

```
#if _WIN32
#include <direct.h>
#define getcwd _getcwd
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ';'
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ':'
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <Python.h>
#include "cquacker.h"

std::wstring getSysPath()
{
  char cwd[FILENAME_MAX];
  getcwd(cwd, FILENAME_MAX);
  std::wstringstream path;
  path << Py_GetPath() << PATH_SEPARATOR << cwd;
  return path.str();
}

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PySys_SetPath(getSysPath().c_str());
  PyInit_cquacker();
  if (PyErr_Occurred())
  {
    PyErr_Print();
    return -1;
  }
  cquack();
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

---

***Edit:*** Extended example, round trip (C++ -> Python -> C++).

quacker.py:

```
def qcallback(duck):
    duck.quack()
```

quacker/Duck.hpp

```
#include <iostream>

namespace quacker {

class Duck
{
public:
    void quack() { std::cout << "Quack!" << "\n"; }
};

}
```

cquacker_defs.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "quacker/Duck.hpp" namespace "quacker":
    cdef cppclass Duck:
        Duck() except +
        void quack()
```

cquacker.pyx:

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr

cimport cquacker_defs

from quacker import qcallback

cdef class Duck:
    cdef shared_ptr[cquacker_defs.Duck] _this

    @staticmethod
    cdef inline Duck _from_this(shared_ptr[cquacker_defs.Duck] _this):
        cdef Duck result = Duck.__new__(Duck)
        result._this = _this
        return result

    def __init__(self):
        self._this.reset(new cquacker_defs.Duck())

    def quack(self):
        assert self._this != NULL
        deref(self._this).quack()


cdef public void cqcallback(shared_ptr[cquacker_defs.Duck] duck):
    qcallback(Duck._from_this(duck))
```

main.cpp:

```
#if _WIN32
#include <direct.h>
#define getcwd _getcwd
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ';'
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ':'
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "quacker/Duck.hpp"

#include <Python.h>
#include "cquacker.h"

std::wstring getSysPath()
{
  char cwd[FILENAME_MAX];
  getcwd(cwd, FILENAME_MAX);
  std::wstringstream path;
  path << Py_GetPath() << PATH_SEPARATOR << cwd;
  return path.str();
}

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PySys_SetPath(getSysPath().c_str());
  PyInit_cquacker();
  if (PyErr_Occurred())
  {
    PyErr_Print();
    return -1;
  }
  auto duck = std::make_shared<quacker::Duck>();
  cqcallback(duck);
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: **boost::python**

Comment: @vz0: "The second question - is Boost.Python a good choice? I need something very fast and, at the same time, easy to use."

Comment: To be clear: I interpreted the question to be open towards alternatives to Boost.Python. You can accomplish the same thing with Boost.Python, it's mainly a matter of personal preference. The Cython version generates fast code and, in my personal opinion, is very easy to use.

Comment: @kloffy thank you for the answer. Can you help me a little bit with cython? How to launch a python function not from the main function, but from the 'somefunc' method of my class without losing context of python variables? I think I need to call Py_Initialize() and other helping functions from constructor of my derived class. Am I right? For example, assume I have do_stuff.py file which has a function named somefunc_py and wants to execute my base classe's method (name it, for example, base_method()) inside that function. If you are able to write what I need to do, that would be great.

Comment: If you would like to wrap a C++ class and expose it to python, it goes a bit beyond the scope of the original question. I can add a quick example, but it would be worth studying the Cython documentation: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html

Comment: @kloffy my application says: 'undefined symbol: cqcallback'

Comment: @AyazSalikhov: It is defined at the bottom of "cquacker.pyx". Don't forget to include the sources generated by `cython --cplus cquacker.pyx` when compiling (in this case "cquacker.cpp").

Comment: @kloffy also, you need to divide Py_GetPath() and cwd with ":", not with ";" on Linux and Mac.

Comment: @AyazSalikhov: Yes, indeed, good point!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121771/discussion-between-ayaz-salikhov-and-kloffy).

Comment: @kloffy one more thing. To make it work with Python 2, you need to do sth. like this:
`#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
#define INITIALIZE initcquacker()
#else
#define INITIALIZE PyInit_cquacker()
#endif`
and then call INITIALIZE instead of specific function in main.cpp