# Call python file with python imports from C using cython

Tags: python, c, cython

This question is based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589868/call-python-code-from-c-via-cython), but with a twist. I want to compile a python function using cython, then call it in C. In this simple case, it works, but when I try to import another python module from my python code, it doesn't work.

world.pyx

```
def world():
    return 10
```

hello.pyx

```
import world

def hello():
    ret = 5 + world()
    return ret

cdef public int call_hello():
    return hello()
```

main.c

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  PyInit_hello();
  int v = call_hello();

  printf("the value is %d\n",v);

  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

cython -3 --force world.pyx hello.pyx
clang -c world.c hello.c main.c -I/Users/aneben/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
clang -L/Users/aneben/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin -lpython3.6m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation world.o hello.o main.o  -o main
```

If I simply move the `world` function into `hello.pyx`, then it works fine. But it doesn't work as written when I import it.

./main

```
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
Exception ignored in: 'hello.call_hello'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `from world import world`?

Comment: Also, if something does not work when I run a program with `--force`, it might be a good idea to look at what is being forced here.

Comment: I think part of your problem is that you are trying to compile two different .pyx files into one module, which doesn't work. Each .pyx file translates into one module.

Answer (score 0):

`import world` imports the *module*, not the function.

In order to call `world()` from a different module, you must use `world.world()`

Comment: Sorry, typo. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to be to add a call to `PyInit_world();` in the main function. Cython adds this function to `world.c`, even though in this case it does not generate a header file, so we get a warning, but it works.

Is there a way to have `hello.c` call `PyInit_world()` automatically, so that `main.c` doesn't need to know about that? In that way, the C include hierarchy would mirror the python one.

Comment: If you compile world.pyx to a separate file like the "import" mechanism expects then it'll work correctly.