# Call Cython (Python3.6) in C++ Program

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x, cython

I'm working on a project where I need to embed some python code in C++. I've been trying Cython for a while, but I still have a lot of questions. Here's a demo that I have tried.

Here I have a couple files with struct and functions:

First, this is file `cat.pyx`

```
cdef public struct Cat:
    int num

cdef public setCatNum(Cat* cat):
    cat.num = 100

cdef public int getCatNum(Cat* cat):
    return cat.num
```

And its `.pxd` file `cat.pxd`:

```
cdef public struct Cat:
    int num

cdef public setCatNum(Cat* )
cdef public int getCatNum(Cat* )
```

And this is my `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("cat", ["cat.pyx"], include_dirs=['.']),
    ]

setup(
  name='dotest',
  cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules=ext_modules,
  script_args=['build_ext'],
  options={'build_ext':{'inplace':True, 'force':True}}
)
```

It could compile correctly, but in the generated `cat.h` file, the function declarations are something else:

`__PYX_EXTERN_C PyObject *__pyx_f_3cat_setCatNum(struct Cat *);
__PYX_EXTERN_C int __pyx_f_3cat_getCatNum(struct Cat *);`

So how could I call those functions in my C/C++ program? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have read [this documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c)? I assume you have, since you're correctly making the functions `public`. I think it should generate simpler names though...

Comment: Yes, I did read through that example. And it says that in python 3.x I should import a module. But I didn't quite see how to use the module to call those functions in the doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's generating mangled names for the public functions - it runs contrary to [the documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c). However it's also doing it for me. I suspect this is a bug, but suggest for the moment you should just use the mangled names.

You probably want to set the return type of `setCatNum` to `void`. Currently it returns a `PyObject*` (always `None`) which isn't useful, and means you have to handle its reference count.

```
cdef public void setCatNum(Cat* )
```

The thing I think you're getting confused by is the difference between Python 2 and 3. The documentation suggests replacing `init<modulename>` with

```
err = PyImport_AppendInittab("modulename", PyInit_modulename);
Py_Initialize();
modulename_module = PyImport_ImportModule("modulename");
```

That's the only change you need to make - you don't actually need to use the module object.

A working example:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "cat.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    auto err = PyImport_AppendInittab("cat", PyInit_cat);
    if (err) {
        std::cout << "ERROR!\n";
        return 1;

    }
    Py_Initialize();
    auto cat_module = PyImport_ImportModule("cat"); // you don't actually have to do anything with this module object
    Cat c;
    __pyx_f_3cat_setCatNum(&c);
    std::cout << __pyx_f_3cat_getCatNum(&c) << "\n";
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

compiles successfully on Linux with

```
g++ example_cpp.cpp -o example `python3-config --includes --libs` ./cat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

(You may have to change the exact `cat` filename)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's also working for me now. But is there any alternative way that I might be able to avoid those name mangling?

Comment: @hiimdaosui This is strange, but when I build with "cython cat.pyx" I get function names without mangling...

Comment: @ead when I try `cython cat.pyx`, it still gives me mangled functions...

Comment: I think this might be a bug that's been introduced in some Cython version. I'd make sure Cython is updated to the most recent version, and if that doesn't solve it file a bug report on github

Comment: I would try removing (or fixing?) `cat.pxd`

Answer (score -3):

The normal cython development pattern is quite the opposite - you would use it to call C++ code from python, instead.

A simple description of cython common usage is "Write your code in high-level python-like language and it gets converted to C source code for a python extension"

The generated C code is not readable, and not meant to be used from C.

tl;dr Use cython to make your C/C++ program callable from python, and write python code to call it.

Comment: This is not what I have discovered from other resources so far. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589868/call-python-code-from-c-via-cython. But I think it's just my code is not working and there might be a solution for it.

Comment: @hiimdaosui I never said it is impossible, just abnormal - like swimming against the tide

Comment: @hiimdaosui here's a good read https://twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/rant/extendit.html

Comment: okay I see what you are saying here. But in my project, I already have a lot of functionalities coded in python, and they are heavily dependent on some third party libs like opencv and tensorflow. But ultimately I need to use a C++ program to call those functions. So I'm quite confused here. Do I have to rewrite all of those code in C++?

Comment: @hiimdaosui *"but I need to use a C++ program to call those functions"* why? That is probably false! What is forcing you to call them from C++? Can't you just use python and call the C++ part from python instead?

Comment: The problem is that my client is building up a C++ program which needs my functionalities to make some predictions via my tf model. So it'd be the best if I can make my python code to some libraries that callable from C++ side.

Comment: I see, artificial restrictions! That's too bad @hiimdaosui - I wouldn't use cython for this myself, because while possible, it seems to make things harder - did you consider spawning a python process separately and using some form of inter-process comunication to send data to/from the C++ part?

Comment: I haven't done that yet. But after today's discussion, I will definitely give it a try. But also, this program sort of has some performance requirements (another reason why I tried Cython), so (if any), is there any other "faster" strategies that I may be able to use under this scenario?