# Installing scrapy on mac - pyasn1 distribution not found

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, pyasn1

I have installed scrapy on my mac (OS El Capital, 10.11.4), there does not seem to be any compatibilty problem between scrapy and my python version (2.7.11) but when I try to start a project with `scrapy startproject tutorial` I get following error message:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pyasn1' distribution was not 
found and is required by service-identity
```

I have tried updating both the pyasn1 and the service identity package, but that did not change anything. I have not found any help regarding this specific problem.

Has anyone ever experienced a similar problem? Is there a solution (even a "brutal" one, like uninstalling everything to start from scratch)?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly you installed scrapy and why the dependencies were not pulled in automatically, but would  just "pip install pyasn1" or "easy_install pyasn1" help? I suspect other dependencies may not be satisfied as well.

Comment: When I type `pip install pyasn1` I get `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` then when I upgrade it I get `Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.
Somehow the problem seems to be deeper?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to install everything from scratch. I suggest you to build scrapy in a separate python environment. In my case, a simple `pip install cryptography` in my environment solved this issue.

Comment: This worked for me when I upgraded my server from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was due to El Capitan getting rid of openssl headers.  This was causing cryptography build to fail.

I found the answer by following:
[Install Scrapy on OS X El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412529/install-scrapy-on-os-x-el-capitan)

The important parts are:

```
brew install openssl
env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography  
pip install --upgrade scrapy
```