# Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix> ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python-2.7

I got a error that I can't solve, wish somebody can help me!

I am installing  the openstack components ,  Firstly,I install the python in the source code way. But after I process the steps of "download the source package"、"unzip files"、"compile" and “make  install” , I believe that I have finish the installation procedure.  But when I execute the command of 
         "ln -s /usr/local/python2.7/bin/python   /bin/python2.7"
or the command of 
         "python ",
It throw the follow error:

```
    Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
    Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
    Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
    ImportError: No module named site
```

I searched in the net, but there is no method, and I dont't know how to do.

so, would anybody teach me about this?

thanks very much!

PS:  my python installed in the director of "/usr/local/python2.7"
     and my version is "python 2.7.12"

```
 I try to install the "pip" and "setuptools",,there are the same errors .
```

Thanks very much !

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292957/how-can-i-troubleshoot-python-could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-pr?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I troubleshoot Python "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292957/how-can-i-troubleshoot-python-could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-pr)