# Python install requests

Tags: python, pip

I am very new to programming and I am trying to install the package requests to python.

In the terminal on my mac I am entering `pip install requests`.

I am getting the following error message.

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fff9e4ac3c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

I would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: How did you install pip?

Comment: Maybe first thing to try is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292957/how-can-i-troubleshoot-python-could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-pr)

Comment: I am now seeing the error message. Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Answer (score 0):

I think pip does not know where you python is. You can try to set the environment variable

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local
```

If the location of your python is NOT `/usr/local`, get the correct location using

```
which python
```

For example, on my computer `which python` gives `/usr/bin/python`. So, I would do `export PYTHONHOME=/usr/bin` on my computer before using `pip install`.