# Spark: No module named 'encoding'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I submit my `test.py` to yarn as follows.

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--executor-memory 8g \
--driver-memory 10g \
--num-executors 100 \
--executor-cores 10 \
--conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=/home/ml_env/ml_env.zip#pyenv \
--conf spark.pyspark.python=./pyenv/bin/python3 \
test.py
```

Here, I want to import some python packages, such numpy, configparser package, so I build a virtual environment named `ml_env`.

In `ml_env` environment, I first use `virtualenv ml_env`, and the `source activate`, then I pip install `numpy` and `configparser` on `ml_env`.

My `test.py` is shown as follow.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

import configparser
import numpy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    distData = sc.parallelize(data)
    print("done",distData.collect())
```

But I meet an error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings

Comment: I have read it, and try to rebuilt the virtual env, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Which environment are you using? python version, macOS, Win?

Comment: I use python 3.7 installed by anaconda, and Linux.

Comment: is python path set correctly?
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

Comment: The `sys.path` is `['', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`.

Comment: You tried unsetting the python path? 
And i am not sure in your submit statement you are using "--conf spark.pyspark.python=./pyenv/bin/python3 \" but you want to use the conda one right?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the virtualenv as python environment.

Comment: Mh maybe you will find something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292957/how-can-i-troubleshoot-python-could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-pr I think i cant help u further. sry. But i think some path variables are messed up