# aws: Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

Tags: python, aws-cli

Running `aws` gives me:

```
aws
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f8748e0c740 (most recent call first):
[1]    780469 abort (core dumped)  aws
```

Any suggestions on how to fix?

The given suggestion:

`Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]` doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19292957/8438982