# arm-none-eabi-gdb cannot start because of some python error

Tags: c++, c, gcc, arm, embedded

I'm trying to use arm-none-eabi-gdb as the debugger for my stm32 project, but when I try to execute it, it return the following error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f75639ddc00 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I look online and find this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292957/how-can-i-troubleshoot-python-could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-pr), but when I enter `export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local` it come out annother error message that I cannot find any solution:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fcc24680c00 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've check that my python and python3 work ok, Is there anything I should check for?

Thank you ~

The arm gcc_tool_chain version I'm using is 11.2-2022.02 for x86_64 Linux hosted which I download from the official [website](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads). And After downloading it, I just unzip it and add the toolchain directory into `$PATH`. I did not compile or install and I'm not sure if I should do any of those since I download the binary version(gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz) and the arm-none-eabi-g++ compiler works perpectly.

Comment: you could try doing `pip install encodings` or the equivalent.  it looks like python is trying to load that and its not available.

Comment: @RussSchultz I tried, but it cannot find that module: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement encodings (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for encodings'`

Comment: @Benycu Could you please augment your question with the exact distribution of Linux and version of Python3 you are using for your development ?

Comment: @Frant Thank you replying ~~ Sorry I waited so long to reply.    After multiple time of trying, I decided to reinstall the entire OS. But I still cannot run it. Then I try to install from source and it work!!      Although the install-from-source compiler is lack of nano library, I thought it is enough for me.       But for future references, the OS i'm using is Ubuntu 20.04 and the python version I have are python2.7, python3.6, and python3.8.

Comment: I suspect that 'encoding' is related to a python string.  The API in 'C' to use strings is local aware.  It looks like a configure error in GDB; you are using the tools for cross debugging. The <prefix> and <execprefix> are probably '\0' which is an unknown python string local.   For instance there is 'gdb-multiarch' under Debian/Ubuntu.  It gave me better results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you truncated the message you received! I had same problem.
arm-none-eabi-gdb  looks for specific python version that explained at end of the message! Mine was 3.8 whereas I already had 3.10. so I decided to install python 3.8 in parallel with my installed version. After some search I found a way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt update
sudo apt install python3.8
```

You can find more information in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-multiple-alternative-versions-of-python-on-ubuntu-20-04-237be5177474) site.

Comment: I can confirm this worked, but i had to edit ppa after adding as i have newer OS which is not supported. So edit target to jammy worked also on newer ubuntu 22.10

Comment: correct ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Answer (score 1):

It is weird that on my machine with python3.10 and kubuntu 22.10 it is working with gdb from 10.3. But 11.3 is complaining

Answer (score 1):

As of ARM GCC 12.3 Rel1 the full error output on my system looked something like:

```
~ » arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007efce1a50c00 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Notice `/usr/lib/python3.8` in `sys.path`, and `program name = '/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'`.

From this info we can gather that:

1. `arm-none-eabi-gdb` depends on Python 3.8
2. It's looking for the python binary at `'/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'`

#### Solution

I prefer [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage virtual environments and python installs, so I used it to resolve the issue with the following steps:

1. [Install pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) and setup your environment.  Their auto installer works well:

```bash
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

2. Install [Python build dependencies](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment).  As of 11/9/2023:

```bash
sudo apt update; sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

3. `pyenv install 3.8.18`
4. `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bld-tools`
5. `sudo ln -s $PYENV_ROOT/versions/3.8.18 /usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env`

GDB should now work as expected:

```bash
~ » arm-none-eabi-gdb --version                                                                       jhcarter@jhcarter-X670E
GNU gdb (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.3.Rel1 (Build arm-12.35)) 13.2.90.20230627-git
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately gave up attempting to match the GDB provided with a prebuilt toolchain and the version of python provided with the Linux distribution I am using. The exact python version the GDB was built against should IMHO be provided along with GDB.

I am now building GDB from scratch against the exact version of python provided with my Linux distribution. A pro of using this approach is that I can use the latest and greatest versions of GDB as they are released.

The procedure for building, say, GDB 14.1, against the version of python provided with Ubuntu 20.04.3 would then be:

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libz-dev libexpat1-dev libncurses-dev libgmp-dev \
                        libmpfr-dev libisl-dev libreadline-dev libpython3-dev texinfo texlive

wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-14.1.tar.xz
tar Jxf gdb-14.1.tar.xz
mkdir gdb
cd gdb

../gdb-14.1/configure --with-expat \
                      --target=arm-none-eabi \
                      --program-prefix=arm-none-eabi- \
                      --with-source-highlight \
                      --with-python=$(which python3) \
                      --enable-tui
make -j8 all install
```

Verifying which version of Pythin GDB was linked against:

```bash
ldd /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc1e0b5000)
        libncursesw.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6 (0x00007f2175fc1000)
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f2175f91000)
        libpython3.8.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0 (0x00007f2175a3b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2175a18000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2175a12000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f21759e4000)
        libmpfr.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.6 (0x00007f2175961000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f21758dd000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f21756fb000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f21755ac000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2175591000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f217539f000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2175381000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f217537c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2176a00000)
```

Verifying versions:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 14.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

python3 --version
Python 3.8.10

/usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb --batch -ex 'python import sys; print(sys.version)'
3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35)
[GCC 9.4.0]
```

The same procedure works for more recent versions of Ubuntu as well.