# Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>

Tags: python, c++, windows

I am trying to run the following code:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    std::wcout << std::endl;
    std::wstring pyPath = Py_GetPath();
    std::wcout << L"Paths: " << pyPath << std::endl;

    std::wcout << std::endl;

    std::wstring pyPref = Py_GetExecPrefix();
    std::wcout << L"Exec Prefix: " << pyPref << std::endl;

    PyRun_SimpleString( "print('Hello World from Embedded Python!!!')" );

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;

}
```

And get the following output in my console:

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>

Paths: C:\Program Files\Python311;C:\Program Files\Python311\python311_d.zip;C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib;C:\Program Files\Python311\DLLs

Exec Prefix: C:\Program Files\Python311
Hello World from Embedded Python!!!
```

The question is what should I do to eliminate the "Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>" error? By eliminate I mean to make python to load its libraries correctly.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(PROJ_NAME "Test")

project(${PROJ_NAME})

include_directories( $ENV{PYTHONPATH}/include )
link_directories( $ENV{PYTHONPATH}/libs )

list(APPEND SRC_LIST src/main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJ_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

And these are the values of the system variables:

PYTHONPATH - C:\Programm Files\Python311
PYTHONHOME - C:\Programm Files\Python311

The C:\Programm Files\Python311 path is also present in the PATH system variable

C:\Programm Files\Python311 is the folder where the python 3.11 is installed

When I run python from CMD, it does not show any errors:

```
>python --version
Python 3.11.0

>python
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I troubleshoot Python "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292957/how-can-i-troubleshoot-python-could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-pr)

Comment: The suggested question is related to MacOS, while I am on windows. It also is not clear how the code in that question is invoked. As for re-installing python I've installed a fresh installation of Python 3.11 right before trying to invoke it from C++